# Django Model Object Automatic Filtering

Tags: python, django, django-models, filtering

I am working on a Django project, and I would like do a command like this:
`Student.objects.all().filter(name__iexact="Some name")`

in away that's can be more, well, malleable, e.g:

`someFunction(Student.objects.all(): QuerySet,'name__iexact',"Some name") -> QuerySet`

or:

`Student.objects.all().some_advanced_filter(key='name__iexact',value='Some name') -> QuerySet`

Thanks!

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what you aim to achieve here.

Comment: I added annotations for more clarification, and what I am aiming at here is trying to search a table without having to write the specific key in the method parameter, but pass it as a string or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter by constructing a `Q` object, for example:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Student.objects.filter(Q(('name__iexact', 'some_name')))
```

So you could make `some_function` with:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def some_function(qs, key, value):
    return qs.filter(Q((key, value)))
```

This is in essence what happens when you call a `.filter(..)`. Indeed, it will obtain the `*args` (`Q`-objects), and `**kwargs`, and wrap these in new `Q` objects that are then converted in an *conjunctive* `Q` object.